# SQL query returning rows in sql developer but not in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, asp.net-membership

**Background**
I have configured asp.net membership with oracle 11g. IIS and Oracle 11g express on configured on the same machine. Everything worked fine until I deployed the application on IIS6. My application stopped identifying the users already in database. Searching for a solution brought me to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx) this solution. I updated web.config in Visual Studio 2010 on my client machine and set applicationName to match that on IIS and deleted all existing roles and users records from the database. I then, added an admin role and user using WSAT and since I am also keeping some additional info for users in another table 'UserDetails' I run the following query in oracle sql developer to add admin details

```
insert into UserDetails (userid, usertypeid) VALUES('BC3008FFFAD24BB995C21E80A4870ABA', 1);
```

Which successfully added the record. I built deployment package for the application and deployed it to IIS. Browsed the web application, entered user credentials and yet again the application rejected to let me in.

I run the application from VS on client (without changing anything).
Here is my login page logic

login.aspx:

```
Username: <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserName"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Password: <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" onclick="btnLogin_Click" 
    style="height: 26px" />
```

login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
            {
                MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                Guid guserid = new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                string userid = Helpers.TranslateOraceEndianUserID(guserid);
                int usertype = UserDetailsBAL.GetUserType(userid);
                if (usertype == 1)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard.aspx");
                }                    
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?error");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?error");
            }            
    }
```

putting breakpoint inside `if(Membership.ValidateUser ...` revealed that user is validate, the actual problem is `UserDetailsBAL.GetUserType(userid);`

**Problem**

Stepping into GetUserType

```
public static int GetUserType(string userid)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string q = string.Format("SELECT usertypeid from userdetails where userid='{0}'", userid);
        dt = OraDAL.Select(q);
        int usertype = -1;
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
            usertype = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
        }

        return usertype;
    }
```

and then OraDAL.Select(q)

```
public static DataTable Select(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(query, OpenConn());
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}

private static string connString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)));User Id=...;Password=...";
private static OracleConnection conn;

    public static OracleConnection OpenConn()
    {
        if (conn==null)
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
        }
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

I noticed that the query is not populating dt. Everything seems fine to me and I executed the same query in sql developer which does return a row

[image]

What are the possible areas to inspect in order to track the problem??

**Edit**

I skipped the `GetUserType` for `usertype= 1` in order to allow admin to login to the site and create other users of usertype=2. Now users of usertype=2 can login to the site and `GetUserType` code runs smoothly returning the user types. I made changes to the code in login.aspx.cs:

```
       Guid guserid = new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
       string userid = Helpers.TranslateOraceEndianUserID(guserid);
       int usertype = UserDetailsBAL.GetUserType(userid);
       if (usertype == 2)
       {
          Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard.aspx");
       }
```

**Edit2**

Now that I have users of usertype 2 in database I changed the above code again to see if the it gives error for the usertype=1 again

```
 string userid = Helpers.TranslateOraceEndianUserID(guserid);
 int usertype = UserProfilesBAL.GetUserType(userid);
 if (usertype == 1)
 {
     Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Dashboard.aspx");
 }
 else if (usertype == 2)
 {
      Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard.aspx");
 }
```

Now to add to my frustration when I enter the credentials for the user of type 1, the GetUserType returns nothing and when I login with the credentials of usertype 2, the GetUserType does return user type.

The only difference between these two are that for usertype=1 I manually entered the record in userdetails table using oracle sql developer and for the usertype=2 the record is added by my code when I create user of usertype 2 using create user form in back end.

Here is how I create users and make an entry to userdetails

```
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtUserPass.Text, null, null, null, true, out createStatus);

if (newUser != null)
{
  string userid = Helpers.TranslateOraceEndianUserID(new Guid(newUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()));

  UserDetailsBAL.AddUserDetails(userid, 2)
}
```

In AddUserDetails I am simply inserting the record in user details table.

The worst part is the query generated in `OraDAL.Select` method  that I previously mentioned in my post. Same query when run in asp.net returns null for usertype 1 and when I copy paste it from `query` variable (as shown in above screenshot) into sql developer returns one row.

Comment: Your `OracleDAL.Select` method is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In this case, the parameter value is validated as a `Guid`, but if you're using the method anywhere else, you should rewrite it to use parameterized queries.

Comment: As for the problem with your query, are you absolutely sure that when you run it in sql developer, you're connecting to the same database with the same credentials?

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks a lot for taking time and going through the post. First I will make sure to read about SQL injection and rewrite it using parameterized queries..

Comment: As for as the database is concerned yes it is same database. And there is no problem with the connection string as well. Plz check the updated post.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I also doubt myself that It would be because of me. I must be overlooking something, but I struggled with it for 2,3 hours in the morning trying changing connectionstrings etc etc

Comment: From your update if definitely sounds the the `UserDetails` record is missing for the admin user. One other thought - you inserted into the `UserDetails` table; your screen-shot shows you querying the `userdetails` table; but your code sample is querying the `userprofile` table. Was this a typo?

Comment: @RichardDeeming actually frankly speaking I am stroring the details in userprofile table but somehow I thought to change it to userdetails on this post so that reader may not confuse it with the profile table that asp.net membership creates. Let me edit it in the original post

Comment: There must be some difference in the way the queries are handled between ADO.NET and sql developer. Perhaps the the Oracle client for ADO.NET is duplicating the behaviour of your `Helpers.TranslateOraceEndianUserID` method?